# Multiplos botões compartilhar do facebook, twitter e G+ na mesma página

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, twitter-api

Tenho uma página que contém várias postagens e preciso colocar botões de compartilhar individual em cada postagem.

Veja um exemplo: [Nesse site podemos ver o cenário parecido com o que quero fazer](http://www.humordaterra.com/category/quadrinhos/)

Comment: Mostre como você está tentando, que já vai ajudar. O que já tem pronto, já conseguiu fazer um botão pra compartilhar apenas uma das tiras?

Comment: Você usa uma plataforma de blogs? Tipo Wordpress?

Comment: Outra melhoria, em vez de colocar o link para o site, localize o código e publique aqui. Veja [Posso mostrar só um link pro meu site com problemas?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1913/201). E também: você colocou a tag AngularJS, e isso pode modificar radicalmente a solução necessária. É relevante?

Comment: @Bacco 
O botão funciona compartilhando a página toda. Editei a pergunta e coloquei um link demonstrando como quero fazer.

Comment: @RowAraujo Não uso nenhuma plataforma de terceiros, estou desenvolvendo todo o site.

Comment: Os votos negativos e o voto para encerrar a pergunta (já tem 1, faltam 4) são sinais de problemas com sua formulação. O guia [ask] tem mais dicas pra fazer uma pergunta que recebe votos positivos e respostas, em vez de downvotes e comentários pedindo mais detalhes.

Comment: @Bacco O exemplo do site é exatamente como quero fazer. Penso que os capacitados a responder já conheçam o script e div do share button das redes sociais.

Comment: Se o site sair do ar, ou mudar, ninguém saberá do que se trata.

Comment: A melhor forma que achei para fazer foi usando uma [diretiva angular](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2014/08/01/AngularJS-directives-for-social-sharing-buttons-Facebook-Like-GooglePlus-Twitter-and-Pinterest.aspx) . Com essa diretiva consegui colocar vários botões de likes e compartilhamentos, específico a cada post, em uma mesma página.

Answer (score 1):

Use a plataforma de desenvolvedor de cada site.

[Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button)

[Twitter](https://about.twitter.com/pt/resources/buttons)

[Google Plus](https://developers.google.com/+/web/+1button/?hl=pt-br)

Só colocar na página que englobará a listagem do conteúdo.

Comment: Então, se você olhar no próprio link que você mandou, vai ver que ali há uma listagem de conteúdo, com várias páginas internas. O que você tem que fazer, é colocar esses botões na sua página interna. Não manjo de PHP, mas se não me engano, você pode usar o `REQUEST_URI` para isso.